# Multi-Threading Example output explanation

Tags: c++11

Can anyone please explain to me the output of the below code, I am confused how the threads are executing joining command without letting the main thread to print the Hellos sentences

```
    // example for thread::join
    #include <iostream>       // std::cout
    #include <thread>         // std::thread, std::this_thread::sleep_for
    #include <chrono>         // std::chrono::seconds

    void pause_thread(int n) 
    {
      std::this_thread::sleep_for (std::chrono::seconds(n));
      std::cout << "pause of " << n << " seconds ended\n";
    }

    int main() 
    {
      std::cout << "Spawning 3 threads...\n";
      std::thread t1 (pause_thread,10);
      std::thread t2 (pause_thread,5);
      std::thread t3 (pause_thread,3);
      std::cout << "Done spawning threads. Now waiting for them to join:\n";
      t1.join();
      std::cout << "Hello 1!\n";
      t2.join();
      std::cout << "Hello 2!\n";
      t3.join();
      std::cout << "Hello 3!\n";
      std::cout << "All threads joined!\n";

      return 0;
    }
```

The output:

```
    *Spawning 3 threads...

    Done spawning threads. Now waiting for them to join:

    pause of 3 seconds ended

    pause of 5 seconds ended

    pause of 10 seconds ended

    Hello 1!

    Hello 2!

    Hello 3!

    All threads joined!*
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: By the time `t1.join()` finishes, all `pause of x seconds ended` messages have already been printed, because `t1` takes the longest time to finish. What is unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`join()` blocks until the thread finishes. If the thread finishes before a call to `join()` is made, subsequent `join()` will return immediately. Thus, when you put several `join()` statements in a sequence, you'll block there until all the threads finish, no matter in what order they actually do.

Note that `join()` blocks the thread you call it from, and not the thread you call it for. I.e., in the code snippet, the `main()` thread will wait, but `t1`, `t2` and `t3` will go on until they finish.